# pdf of beta in biparametric canonic form

Tags: exponential-distribution, beta-function, canonical-transformation

I am trying to write the pdf of a beta random variable in its biparametric canonic form such as:

**Function 1**
$$
f_Y(y; \theta,   \phi) = exp \{ \phi[y \theta - b(\theta)] + c(y, \phi) \}  \mathbb{1}_A(y) 
$$

My work so far:

First, I use the beta function so facilitate calculation:

$$
B(\alpha, \beta) =\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\,\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}
$$

than:

**function 2**
$$
f_Y(y; \alpha,  \beta) = exp\{ - log(B(\alpha, \beta)) + (\alpha - 1)log(y) + (\beta-1)log(1-y)\}\mathbb{1}_{[y \in (0,1)]} 
$$

But I am not seeing what would be $ \phi, \theta,c(y, \phi)$ e $b(\theta)$ in function 2.